# How can an ApiController accept multiple variables?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, curl, asp.net-web-api

Can I pass more than one variables to an `[HttpGet]` ApiController action? For example:

```
[HttpGet]
public IPagedList<Something> GetAll(int? page, string sortOrder="")
{
...
}
```

I tested using

```
curl http://localhost:[port]/api/[controller]/GetAll?page=3&sortOrder=Name
```

But the action was never called. The returning message is: No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI. What went wrong?

---Update---

If I check the querystring in HttpActionContext.Request.RequestUri.Query, the `AbsoluteUri` truncated at the ampersand and gives me only `page=3`.

---End of Update

I also tried one variable:

```
[HttpGet]
public IPagedList<Something> GetAll(int? page)
{
...
}
```

The break point inside can be reached without problem in the test

curl http://localhost:[port]/api/[controller]/GetAll?page=3

I also created a view model:

```
public class ListRequestModel
{
    public string SortOrder { get; set; }
    public string CurrentFilter { get; set; }
    public string SearchString { get; set; }
    public int PageNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Action is like:

```
[HttpGet]
public IPagedList<Something> GetAll(ListRequestModel model)
{
...
}
```

Then test

curl http://localhost:[port]/api/[controller]/GetAll?PageNumber=3&SortOrder=Name

This time, the break point inside can be reached, which is a great thing. But the model is null, not populated with the data in the query string.

So, what is the correct way to pass multiple variables into an action method? Please help. Thank you.

----------Update-----------

As requested, pasted below is the Routing Table in the `RouteConfig.cs` file:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

In `Global.asax.cs`, `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();` goes before `RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);` But no Area routes start with `api`. All my other tests on this ApiController can get into the action without problem.

Comment: RegisterAllAreas, RegisterRoutes, Configure and RegisterGlobalFilters.

Are you suspecting our routing table?

Comment: @Blaise Yes, please post your routing table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your routing and setup is fine. And of course that you can pass multiple arguments to a controller.

You just need to improve your Linux foo because `&` has a special meaning in Linux shells...

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ampersand):

> - Some Unix shells use the ampersand as a metacharacter:
> - Some Unix shells, like the POSIX standard sh shell, use the ampersand to execute a process in the background and to duplicate file
>     descriptors.
> - In Bash, the ampersand can separate words, control the command history, duplicate file descriptors, perform logical operations,
>     control jobs, and participate in Regular expressions.

So you need escape the ampersand `&` with a backlash `\` in your your command

```
curl http://localhost:[port]/api/[controller]/GetAll?page=3\&sortOrder=Name
```

Or use quotation marks `""` around the url:

```
curl "http://localhost:[port]/api/[controller]/GetAll?page=3&sortOrder=Name"
```

Comment: Just have a test. Wow! It works! Thank you so much. I am not using a Unix machine. The `\&` method fails. But the quotation marks works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using action-based routing, you are doing it wrong. Try the following:

```
curl http://localhost:[port]/api/[controller]?page=3&sortOrder=Name
```

On the other hand, if you are running the Web API application and ASP.NET MVC under the same context, make sure you register your Web API routes before the MVC ones. Otherwise, default MVC route will catch all your Web API requests and most probably return 404.

Comment: I have used `[HttpGet]` to decorate the actions. Just update my question to reflect this. And I have posted my routing table in the update also. The thing is, some of the actions can be reached without any problem. Only the one I need, which has multiple variables, is having trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Try registering your routes against `HttpRouteCollection` as well.

Answer (score -2):

In your example:

```
[HttpGet]
public IPagedList<Something> GetAll(ListRequestModel model)
{
...
}
```

That will never work, you cannot GET a model, it has to be POST/PUTed.

Comment: I understand why others downvote your post. We can of course send a json data to a GET action.